# String is not getting Copied, after reading the source string from scanf()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  char a[20],*p;
  p=a;
  printf("Enter the String");
  scanf("%s",p);
  printf("\n\n%s\n",p);
  printf("Copying the String\n");
  char b[20],*pp;
  pp=b;
  while((*pp++=*p++));
  printf("\n%s\n",pp);

}
```

This code is not copying Strings. However, If I change `b[20]` to `b[10]`, it's copying last 9 characters of a String. By the way, when I set `b[10]` and if the input consists of a space then it is not copying the strings.

---

Compiler Setup:

Configured with: `--prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: `x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0`
Thread model: `posix`
InstalledDir: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: Why do you use the c++ tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After:

```
    while((*pp++=*p++));
```

`pp` is pointing to the end of the string. You want:

```
     printf("\n%s\n",b);
```

Comment: When b[] is 10, shouldn't be the segmentation​ fault occur? When I passed longer strings, the last 9 characters were being printed, I assume they are passing the array limit.

Comment: @Shan Exceeding the bounds of an array puts you into undefined behaviour land - there is no guarantee of a segmentation fault, or of anything else.

Comment: When I used b[10] and passed a small string (4 chars), the print returned 4 chars. But as you said, the pointer must be pointing to null and no character should be printed, how it's possible